# Quasar Framework Uploader with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, uploader, quasar-framework

A question about the quasar framework uploader component. 
I need to post the images to a URL that will rename the uploaded file and return the full path.

I'm using the **upload-factory** and **axios**

But I'm having problems understanding exactly how to pass the file to axios as if it was just an input type file.
Basically I need to make it as If I'm sending a form with a single input file like this:

```
<input type="file" name="banner">
```

This is the component:

```
<q-uploader
  url=""
  extensions=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"
  :filter="filterFiles"
  :upload-factory="uploadFile" />
```

This is the upload method,  but I keep getting an error response from the server.

```
uploadFile (file, updateProgress) {
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData .set('banner', file)
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
  axios.post('http://someurl/uploadFile', formData , headers)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
}
```

If I post a plain html form with  **method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"** and a

```
<input type="file" name="banner">
```

I get my OK response from the server with the processed/uploaded image URL

Comment: what're the errors when you use axios?

Comment: It's just an ambiguous json server response with ERROR

I dit try using the Advanced REST app and it's same response, so I'm thinking this might not be a Quasar issue after all. 
I'll look more into this and update if I find out something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have successfully done uploading of the file to python API.

---

***V1 Update***

Use `@added -> function(files)` method.

Also `extensions` property is removed now use `accept`

---

This is the component:

```
<q-uploader
  url=""
  extensions=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"
  @add="file_selected"
/>

<q-btn @click="uploadFile()">Upload</q-btn>
```

Data:

```
data() {
  return {
    selected_file:'',
    check_if_document_upload:false,
  }
}
```

Methods

```
file_selected(file) {
  this.selected_file = file[0];
  this.check_if_document_upload=true;
},

uploadFile() {
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("file", this.selected_file);

  axios.post('/uploadFile', fd, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
  }).then(function(response) {
    if(response.data.ok) {
    
    }
  }.bind(this));
}
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @Patel Pratik, But you should change `@add` to `@added` in the `q-uploader`

Comment: Yes, please change `@add` to `@added`. I noticed the comment of Ali Hallaji after reading documentation and fixing that by myself. 
Do a favor for the next generation )

Comment: I have already added that see the and I will move it in the upper section for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully done direct uploading of the file on a button click to python API. But in vue3 and Quasar 2 with some additional formData. Thought might be helpful

This is component:

```
<q-btn
   label="Upload"
   @click="openFilePicker"
/>
<q-uploader
   ref="uploadFile"
   class="hidden"
   accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"
   @added="uploadFileFn"
/>
```

Setup:

```
setup() {
    return {
      uploadFile: ref(null),
    }
  },
```

Methods:

```
openFilePicker() {
   this.$refs.uploadFile.pickFiles();
},
uploadFileFn(file) {
   this.uploadFile = file[0];
   let fd = new FormData();
   fd.append("file", this.uploadFile);
   fd.append("id", "1");
   fd.append("name", "test_user");

   this.$axios.post('/upload_file_with_additional_form_data', fd, {
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
   }).then(
   function (response) {
      if (response.data.success) {
          console.log(response)
      }
   }.bind(this))
}
```

This is working fine for me.