# How can I use formdata in upload file on vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I try like this : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/OJVRjGL?editors=1010

My code :

```
<v-form>
  <v-file-input multiple 
                v-model="documents"
                label="File input"></v-file-input>
  <v-btn color="success" @click="submit()">
    test
  </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

but it does not works

if I upload file and click button test, the formdata empty on the console

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the spread operator to view formdata. FormData is part of the XMLHttpRequest spec.

```
console.log(...formData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print formData directly on the console.

Try this.

```
// Display the key/value pairs
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/OJVRjGL?editors=1010

Comment: I want to ask. What's the difference between sending using formdata and not using formdata?

Comment: formdata used when you want to send the file using Axios

Comment: I send the file using axios

Comment: I get reference that it only to add `headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }`

Comment: example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784888/quasar-framework-uploader-with-axios

Comment: I use v-file-input (vuetify). Can you give an example using vuetify?